# Used html button instead of apex command button,controller action not updating new values?why

Tags: apex, html, commandbutton, actionfunction

Used html button instead of apex command button, but  only old values are passing to contrller action method why? Its working fine for commandbutton!!

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="initiateactionmethod" reRender="basicid" action="{!updatedetails}" status="AjaxLoader" oncomplete="window.location.reload( true );">

        </apex:actionFunction> 

 <input type="button" class="button-a blue"  onclick="initiateMethod();"  value="save"/>
```

previous command button::

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save"   styleClass="button-a blue"  action="{!updatedetails}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values from your page are sent to a controller on form **submit**. You can see this if you view HTML code generated by your visualforce page `<apex:commandButton/>` will be an input with `type="submit"`.

So try changing the type of your button:

```
 <input type="submit" class="button-a blue"  onclick="initiateMethod();"  value="save"/>
```

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: its working fine ,but i need to send values from javascript for that fields its not working

Comment: if i keep submit its only submitting form data

Comment: I`m not sure that I understand what do you need now. If you need to excecute javascript before submit, call it in onclick and then call actionfunction from there.

Comment: thanks Oles Malkov,i have implemented this successfully,working fine,

Comment: I need to make the html input of `type="button"` to pass new values to controller.